# Windows phone communicating over bluetooth with another Android app

Tags: android, bluetooth, windows-phone

I'm developing an WinPhone 8.1 app, is it possible to send some small data (<100 kB sqlite data) to another Android application?
I know app-to-app only works if it's an instance of the same application, but this is not the case here, or I think so.
Application are developed independently, but are serving almost the same purpose, and may have identical name.

1. Will app-to-device work here or is it reserved only for embedded devices?
   If I pair winphone and android outside of an app, will PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:PAIRED"] = ""; be able to find android phone inside an app?
2. How does WinPhone check if it's an instance of the same application, so called peer app?

Comment: 'I know app-to-app only works if it's an instance of the same application'. No. Why wouldn't work? It's just sending data over sockets. Of course that can work.

Comment: I can't find any devices using Peerfinder class.

From MSDN article "Bluetooth For Windows Phone 8" on app-to-app:
"PeerFinder" gives you the ability to discover another instance of your app on a nearby device, and create a socket connection between these peer apps. A peer app is another instance of an app running on another device."

*note: friend can discover me in his Android app, APIs are different.